# Why can I not have an abstract and static method in the same class in Java

Tags: java, abstract-class, static-methods

I have the following class:

```
public abstract class A
{
  public abstract String doSomething(String X, String Y);
  public static String doSomething(String X, String Y){return X + Y;}
  ...
}
```

The issue I have is that the static and abstract `doSomething()` methods seem to clash as duplicates.  I thought this should be fine because the static method belongs to the class, not an instance of the class, so I was going to use the abstract method to enforce the method on all subclasses and the static method as a helper so that I have nicely factored code.

I know I could probably add an interface into the mix, but I don't really understand what's wrong with my abstract and static methods existing on the same class.  What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java it is valid (despite being misleading and confusing) to call a static method from an object instance rather than the class name (despite *warnings* generated by many compilers).

```java
System.out.println(String.valueOf(true)); // Prints "true".
System.out.println("".valueOf(true)); // Prints "true", unfortunately.
```

So the following *seemingly* valid code wouldn't know which of those methods to call:

```java
A a = getInstanceOfConcreteSubclassOfA();
a.doSomething(null, null); // Compiler can't decide which method to call...
```

Unfortunately, it's just one of the few ugly corners of the Java language.

Comment: To clarify slightly: it's the compiler, not the runtime, that would have to figure out which method to call.

Comment: You can't override static methods. Can you?

Comment: @srikanthradix: nope, static methods cannot be overridden.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't call it ugly.  The joy of Java is that it blocks you from doing things which are misleading. This is a great example.  If you want a "helper" method, then it is better to give it a different name so that someone reading your code sees the difference at a glance between the method itself and its helper.

Comment: @couling: It's ugly because it *is* misleading. `a.staticMethod()` looks like it's calling a non-static virtual method, but it's actually calling a static non-virtual method. And `((A)null).staticMethod()` looks like it should throw a `NullPointerException`, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

It's not specific to abstract methods; in general, Java doesn't let you have two methods with the same parameter-types but one being static and one not. Something like this:

```
public String doSomething(String X, String Y){return X + Y;}
public static String doSomething(String X, String Y){return X + Y;}
```

would also be illegal.

(This makes sense when you consider that you're allowed to call a static method "on" an actual instance, or for that matter, on any expression of the appropriate type. The compiler translates `((A)null).staticMethod()` to `A.staticMethod()`.)

Answer (score 1):

Each method has a signature composed of:

```
method name
parameter type
Return type
```

If 2 methods have the same signature, this will cause an error.

the word `static` does **not** interfere in the signature of the method just like `const`.